# Is Remote Views(Android) good option for creating custom push notification(GCM)?

Tags: android

My Primary focus is to change the existing UI of my push notification
I tried using remote views but facing a problem of creating the object of remote view class as the package name is null at that point of time

Any help is greatly appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: Please share your effort.

Comment: Is remote View a good option?Shall i proceed with it>?

Comment: and i was creating the object of remote view in a service class may be because of this its returning null(package Name)

Answer (score 0):

> My Primary focus is to change the existing UI of my push notification

Because that has nothing to do with `GCM`.
I would recommend you to take a look [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html), as is covered in the documentation